# How to pull code from the master in eGit to my local branch in eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have created a branch in GitHub with master as my source branch. ("Master" is the main branch where all my codes are getting updated on daily basis.) I will be working in my local branch through eclipse. Every now and then I need to pull the code from master to my branch if there is any update in the master. Let me know how to pull code from master to branch through eclipse Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eclipse Neon (and probably Mars too): right-click on a connected project > Team > Pull... . Select to pull from the master branch.

Comment: Any idea on how to do the same in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: It's possible too, but the workflow is more complicated (involves fetch and merge). I strongly recommend you to upgrade to Neon, it's worth it and I don't think you'll find many people glad to help you with a 3 years-old version of Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I will try upgrading to Eclipse Neon. Thanks for the help! Appreciate it! In case If you have any document for Luna for the same process kindly share!